# Simultaneous equations involving indices

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Please can someone help me solve this. I saw it in a text but I have tried to solve all to no avail.

$$3^x + 9^{2y} = 27\\2^x + 4^{-y} = \frac18 $$

Find 2$x$ + 3$y$

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5Ex%2B9%5E(2y)%3D27,2%5Ex%2B4%5E(-y)%3D1%2F8) does not find a solution.  What is the source of the problem?

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ integers?

Comment: @BillO'Haran I believe there are no solutions in the integers

Comment: My thought as well, but at least it would have been solved immediately.

Comment: In fact, no integer values of $x$ or $y$ solve either equation, all the way up to $x,y=\pm1000$

Comment: Something is wrong with the problem, at least assuming you wanted a solution over the real numbers.  If you found the problem "in a text", you should cite the book (author, title, date of publication).  Your own approaches to solving the problem would have improved the Question.

Comment: I just don't know what is going on there. Let me edit with the full question

Comment: Mathematica gives the answer as:$$\left\{x\to \frac{\log \left(27-3^{4 y}\right)}{\log (3)}\right\}$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
   3^x + 9^{2y} &= 27\\
   3^{4y} &= 3^3 - 3^x \\
   3^{4y} &< 3^3 \\
   y &< 0.75 \\
\hline
   2^x + 4^{-y} &= \frac18 \\
   2^{-2y} &= 2^{-3} - 2^x \\
   2^{-2y} &< 2^{-3} \\
   -2y &< -3 \\
   y &> 1.5
\end{align}

Since we can't have both $y < 0.75$ and $y > 1.5$, there is no solution.

[image]